# Use a table of contents to load other web pages into the same page

Tags: html, tableofcontents

I am creating a training site where I have a table of contents on the left side of my page (currently using a DIV to contain that).  I want the table of contents to have links to other external html pages that contain the content for the particular topic, but instead of taking me to that stand-alone web page for that content, I would like that content to be displayed (with the ability to scroll) within another DIV on the same page as the table of contents.  By simply clicking through the different topics it would refresh and load the content on the right side.

I have built pages with 2 DIVs where I have the main body of the page in one div, and a table of contents in the second.  The table of contents links to specific sections in the main body using the # anchor.  But in this case, I don't want to build my entire training content in a single page and jump to different sections.  Instead I want to have each topic be bite-sized into a separate HTML page and load it as necessary when clicking on the specific topic.

My knowledge of web design and terminology is limited, and so I work best by looking at other code that has already been developed, breaking it down, and tweaking it to my needs if there is anything out there that anyone is willing to share (assuming this can be done easily with traditional HTML and JavaScript code).  I have seen similar topics where people want to load a specific page into an existing page upon opening, and mine needs to be dynamic to load any page at will.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I apologize if this question has been asked and answered already.